# How to join a server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to setup a discord bot with python. I have a pre-existing discord server that I would like the bot to join, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    print(client)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        counter = 0
        tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Calculating messages...')
        async for log in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=100):
            if log.author == message.author:
                counter += 1

        await client.edit_message(tmp, 'You have {} messages.'.format(counter))
    elif message.content.startswith('!sleep'):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Done sleeping')

client.run('token')
```

This is essentially the basic discord.py script as given on the GitHub page. However, I can't seem to figure out how to have it actually join my server. When inserting this line into the `on_ready` function:

```
server = await client.accept_invite('instant-invite-code')
```

with "instant-invite-code" replaced with my actual instant invite code (I tried both discord.gg/code and code), I get

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Bots cannot use this endpoint
```

Logging does actually work; I get output with my username and id. My bot is registered with the discord API and I already have a token.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to actually join a server using the desktop app or a browser with your bot account. Once you do, the bot will recognize that it has joined it previously.

Comment: So, I did try this- I logged into the account that the bot was authorized from and joined the correct server, but it doesn't seem to have had an effect- it is still not joining the server (the value of client.servers is []).

Comment: I wonder instead if I am not logging in as the bot- I authorized the bot from the account (and that is where the token was generated), but I'm still logging in to the mac client using e-mail and password.

Comment: @Goodies - is there a way to actually log into the bot user in the web interface given the bot username/id/token?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had some trouble with this as well. What you need to do is:

1. Go to the [Discord developer pages](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me) (login if you haven't).
2. Go to the application with the bot you want to add to your channel.
3. Copy the Client/Application ID.
4. Go to https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE&scope=bot&permissions=0 < You can set permissions for the bot here. [Permissions can be calculated here](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html).
5. Select server and click authorize.

Your bot will now be a member of the server and will respond to commands you give it. Ex. !test in the code you have given.

EDIT: You can now use the permissions link ([1](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html)) to generate the entire URL needed.

Comment: I used this at some point, and it didn't work even though I had all permissions on the server.  When the actual creator of the server did it, however, it worked fine.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: You need to have Manage Server to be able to add bots to a server. This stops random users from adding their own bots, which was a problem from back when bot accounts didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

It's been 4 years since I asked the question and here's how I deal with this problem nowadays.

I use https://discordapi.com/permissions.html where you just paste your bot's ID (which you can get here: https://discord.com/developers/applications ) and it also has the benefit of calculating whatever permissions configuration you want for you.

If you're lazy, this could be a decent solution for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest editing the code like this:

```
    @client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('Invite: https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={}&scope=bot'.format(client.user.id))
    print('------')
```

I think this is the best and easiest solution. It works for me.

EDIT: Discord actually made their own OAuth2 url generator, so use that: https://discordapp.com/developers/tools/oauth2-url-generator

Comment: Does not work for bots created before Bot and Client IDs were merged.