# How do I make an account I logged into with a discord.py bot join a specific server

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically, in discord.py, I can use the login function like this:

```
client.login("email", "password") or client.login("token")
```

now, I have multiple questions (do I need to store the login function in a variable to access the member I log into's data?), but the most important that I would want an answer for, is can I make that member that I logged into join a specific server that I want (given an invite)?

Comment: This depends slightly on the discord.py version and sounds like you're trying to use this as a self bot...

Comment: Its the normal discord.py version (not he rewrite) on 3.6 python, can you help me?

Comment: If you are using this as a regular discord bot, use `client.run(token)` `login()` I believe is for self bots.

Comment: I mean to log into an account, but just when for example a command is executed and then make the account you logged into join a specific server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689289/how-to-join-a-server)

Comment: Yea, definitely look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743722/225020) to the question linked above.

Comment: Thats not what I want to do

Comment: I figured it out now anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer possible with the current Discord.py version.

[Further clarification here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=run#discord.ext.commands.Bot.run)