# How would I add this function into a python discord bot and get it to print to discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking for some guidance on how to add this function to my bot and have it print to discord.
I want the bot to be able to print the results to discord instead of my terminal like so when the command /combat is entered

```
import random

def combat():
    hp = random.randint(1, 11)
    ac = random.randint(1, 7)
    print('Your HP is', hp, 'and your armor is', ac)

    ehp = random.randint(1, 11)
    eac = random.randint(1, 7)
    print("My HP is", ehp, 'and my armor is', eac)
    i = 0
    while not hp < 0 | ehp < 0:
        """add counter"""
        i = i + 1
        '''hp = random.randint(1,11)
        ac = random.randint(1,7)
        print(hp, ac)
        ehp = random.randint(1,11)
        eac = random.randint(1,7)
        print(ehp, eac)'''

        print('Turn',i,':')
        dmg = random.randint(1,9)
        tdmg = dmg - eac
        if tdmg < 0:
            tdmg = 0
        ehp = ehp - tdmg
        print(' You dealt', tdmg, 'damage to me')
        print(' I am at', ehp, 'health')

        edmg = random.randint(1,9)
        tedmg = edmg - ac
        if tedmg < 0:
            tedmg = 0
        hp = hp - tedmg
        print(' I dealt', tedmg, 'damage to you')
        print(' You are at', hp, 'health')
        if ehp < 1:
            print('You win')
            break
        elif hp < 1:
            print('I win')
            break
combat()
```

```
Your HP is 3 and your armor is 5
My HP is 7 and my armor is 3
Turn 1 :
 You dealt 0 damage to me
 I am at 7 health
 I dealt 3 damage to you
 You are at 0 health
I win
```

Comment: Do you have a basic Discord bot setup? (Such as a client and one or so event listeners?)

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you already have a bot token.  If not, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689289/how-to-join-a-server).

You need to create your bot, register the command, and convert it to be asynchronous and use `send` instead of `print`.  You're also relying on `print` to build some of your outputs, which I have replaced with f-strings.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot("/")

@bot.command()
async def combat(ctx):
    hp = random.randint(1, 11)
    ac = random.randint(1, 7)
    await ctx.send(f'Your HP is {hp} and your armor is {ac}')

    ehp = random.randint(1, 11)
    eac = random.randint(1, 7)
    await ctx.send(f'My HP is {ehp} and my armor is {eac}')
    i = 0
    while hp > 0 and ehp > 0:
        i = i + 1

        await ctx.send(f'Turn {i}:')
        dmg = random.randint(1,9)
        tdmg = dmg - eac
        if tdmg < 0:
            tdmg = 0
        ehp = ehp - tdmg
        await ctx.send(f' You dealt {tdmg} damage to me')
        await ctx.send(f' I am at {ehp} health')

        edmg = random.randint(1,9)
        tedmg = edmg - ac
        if tedmg < 0:
            tedmg = 0
        hp = hp - tedmg
        await ctx.send(f' I dealt {tedmg} damage to you')
        await ctx.send(f' You are at {hp} health')
        if ehp < 1:
            await ctx.send('You win')
            break
        elif hp < 1:
            await ctx.send('I win')
            break

bot.run("Token")
```

Comment: So to send variables you have to use {} around it instead of leaving it blank?

Comment: @TarielReckonerofNerds That's the syntax for f-strings, you can [read about them here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).  You could also do `"I am at " + str(ehp) + " health"`, for example.